# What is the time format in the Salesforce Trust API

Tags: trust

The Salesforce Trust API returns the time in the following format:-

> 2017-01-26T02:57:00.000Z

How is this time to be interpreted?

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the supported [date-time](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004680&type=1) formats, which is always used by the API for date-time values:

> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ

Where:

- YYYY is the four-digit year
- MM is the 2 digit month
- DD is the 2 digit day
- T is a literal T that separates the date from the time
- hh is the 24-hour format hour (00-23)
- mm is the 2 digit minute (00-59)
- ss is the 2 digit second (00-60) *(Leap seconds can cause the value 60)*
- SSS is the 3 digit millisecond (000-999)
- Z is the standard designation for GMT-00:00 (Greenwich Mean Time)

This is essentially the format recommended by [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) international date/time format.